# Possible to typedef 'num' to 'float' in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm finding myself jumping back and forth between dart, c, and glsl with the same code and I was wondering if it was possible to make my life a bit easier by typedef'ing, or somehow otherwase aliasing `num` to be named `float`.

Clearly the following doesn't work:

```
typedef num float;
```

Though I wish it did. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: So you just need this to make porting easier? I think the only chance is to write some sort of transformer to replace "float" with "num" but that might be quite hard.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need this? Why don't you just use "double" as a type directly like this:

`double myVar`

Dart supports three different types for numbers: `num`, `double` and `int` where num can be an int or double. You should use `num` when you don't care or don't know the exact type. Otherwise you should use `int` or `double`.

Comment: I think you mean `double` instead of `float`, no?  According to the [dart language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#built-in-types), the number types are `int` and `double`, `float` doesn't compile.  I'd be fine using double except that it is rarely used in the C, C++, glsl code I work with, hence why I'd like to somehow define `float` in dart to make porting faster.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. That should be double :) I changed my code accordingly.